# Need suggestions to correct coding below,everything is ok from my side but (missing { errors appear

Tags: errors

```
\begin{align*}
c\max 
\biggl\{ 
&\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L\leqslant0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}\mu_j 2^{-jn}\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} \norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}}
\, \biggr)^{q_1(0)}\biggr)^{1/q_1(0)},\\
&\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L>0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
\biggl[ 
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}}
\,\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}\mu_j 2^{-jn}\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} \norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}}
\, \biggr)^{q_1(0)}\biggr)^{1/q_1(0)}\\
&\qquad +
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{L}
\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}\mu_j 2^{-jn}\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} \norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}}
\, \biggr)^{q_1(\infty)}\biggr)^{1/q_1(\infty)} \,
\biggr] 
\biggr\}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: A quick hint: If you hightlight a code chunk and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editor window, the site software will pretty-print it automatically.

Comment: You've posted several queries in the meantime and received comments to show not only a code chunk but a complete [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001). It's really important to state which document class is in use, which packages are loaded, and how or where macros such as `\norm` and `\smashoperator` are defined.

Comment: You've received several answers to your earlier queries, but (so far at least) you've not "accepted" any of them. On this site, the main way to express appreciation for answers is to upvote answers you find useful and to accept the answer that you find is most useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `\smashoperator[r]{...}` correctly: The argument of `\smashoperator` *must* be a "math operator" such as `\sum` or `\prod` along with its lower and upper limits -- *and nothing else*. To give an example: The expression

```
\smashoperator[r]{2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty} ...}
```

is not correct. It should be

```
\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}} 2^{k\alpha_2(0)} ...
```

Observe that `2^{k\alpha_2(0)} ...` now comes *after* `\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}}`.

You should also enclose the argument of the first `\sup` expression in square brackets, and you should change the alignment points (marked with `&`) in all three rows in order to make sure the material fits inside the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&c\max \Biggl\{ 
\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L\leqslant0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
\Biggl[2^{-L\lambda} 
\biggl(\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^{L}\!
\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}}
2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\mu_j 2^{-jn}\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} 
\norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}
\biggr)^{\!q_1(0)}\, \biggr)^{\!\!1/q_1(0)}\Biggr],\\
&\quad\sup_{\smash[b]{\substack{L>0,\\ L\in\mathbb{Z}}}} 
\Biggl[ 
2^{-L\lambda} \biggl(\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}
\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}}
2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\mu_j 2^{-jn}
\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} \norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}
\biggr)^{\!q_1(0)}\, \biggr)^{\!\!1/q_1(0)}\\
&\quad +2^{-L\lambda} 
\biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{L} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{L} 
\biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{j=k+4}^{+\infty}}
2^{k\alpha_2(0)}\mu_j 2^{-jn}
\norm{b_j}_{p_{2(.)}} \norm{\chi_{C_j}}_{p_{2(.)}}
\biggr)^{\!q_1(\infty)}\, \biggr)^{\!\!1/q_1(\infty)} 
\Biggr] \Biggr\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```